# A few related riddles

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

I have a few related riddles:

I crawl up fences,
in camouflage green,
One of fastest of my type,
that you've ever seen,
Sweet berries I bring,
Used in jam and that kind of thing.

I'm very tall,
My body is hard and brown,
My head is a green crown,
I have some sweet liquid unseen,
I'm cut down for my resource,
A popular four letter noun.

I cover the ground,
Can be found all around,
Short and small,
Numbers make me tall,
The most common plant of all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For number 1

> Bushes or ivy?

I crawl up fences,
in camouflage green,

> Yep!

One of fastest of my type,
that you've ever seen,

> They can grow very fast.

Sweet berries I bring,
Used in jam and that kind of thing.

> Berry bushes.

For number 2

> Tree

I'm very tall,
My body is hard and brown,

> They can be very tall and these are the colors.

My head is a green crown,

> The leafs.

I have some sweet liquid unseen,

> Syrup!

I'm cut down for my resource,

> Wood.

A popular four letter noun.

> Tree

For number 3

> Grass

I cover the ground,

> It is everywhere.

Can be found all around,

> Yep.

Short and small,
Numbers make me tall,

> Yes.

The most common plant of all.

> On almost every lawn.

Comment: Correct, can you get the others?

Comment: @RohitJose, how about now? :D

Comment: Correct for 2 and 3, for 1, you are close, but a berry bush doesn't climb up fences

Comment: Could it be rot13(vil)?

Comment: @Rohit jose. Can 1 be Blackberry? That climbs fences.

Comment: @RHA Yes it is! In England we have blackberries everywhere. Edit it into an answer and I’ll +1 it.

Comment: @Rohit Not only in the UK; same here on the continent as you British call it.

Comment: Hmm... I didn't know It grew so much elsewhere in Europe. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

Number 1 is

> Blackberry.
>  It climbs or even overgrows fences.
>  It has dark green leaves.
>  The berries make an excellent jam.